# Telerik OpenAccess mapping

Tags: telerik-open-access

While mapping class to table,one of property is not found in table but it is define in configuration:

configuration.HasProperty(x => x.CanEdit).HasFieldName("_canEdit").WithDataAccessKind(DataAccessKind.ReadWrite).ToColumn("canEdit").IsNullable().HasColumnType("bit").HasPrecision(0).HasScale(0).HasDefaultValue();

So when I'm trying to get data "Invalid column name 'canEdit'.
Statement(s) could not be prepared." how to resolve.

Comment: I want this property in mapping

Answer (score 0):

The property should also be added in the POCO class. Only adding it to the mapping is not sufficient.

Add a `public bool? canEdit` property with a `private bool? _canEdit`